# Is their any responsive lightbox with slideshow that has proper swipe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, responsive-design, touch

I have been search for hours for a jquery type plugin that is responsive and also has proper swipe animation during gesture.

http://www.photoswipe.com/ is 99% there except that it dosent support single image lightbox mode, its geared towards grouping images into swipable galleries, which it does brilliantly.

However now and then I may want a few images on a page to have no relation to each other. Id rather have a default class, that when used all images opened up in a single image lightbox. Photoswipe automatically groups any images given the same class.

If I was able to set an option with this plugin to hide the prev/next images on a call, then it would have been perfect.

Important though, is that the plugin must use full screen like photoswipe does. So many responsive plugins seem to waiste the screen with unrequired image chrome. The intended slide show or light box should be like viewing a gallery on a smartphone - again photoswipe does this. its only fall back in being able to have non related instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple out there that appear to be inline with what you want.  I never understood why some developers create "responsive" galleries, but waste so much space with padding or decretive chrome elements.

I was thinking of using PhotoSwipe, but the developers stopped supporting it and recently threw it out there for the open source community to maintain.  Kind of turned me off during the transition.

Here are a few others I came across that I'm considering myself.

**Need higher rep to post more links....so some are just cut and paste.  Sorry.**

JuiceBox
   (http://juicebox.net/)

SwipeBox
  (http://brutaldesign.github.io/swipebox/)

*(full disclosure...I have an affiliate code for the next links. If you want to remove them, just don't add the "ref".  If this helps, I appreciate the clicks)*

Touch N Swipe
(`http://codecanyon.net/item/touch-n-swipe-image-gallery/5886023?ref=bmoe`)

Flare (wow)
(`http://codecanyon.net/item/flare-responsive-mobileoptimized-lightbox-plugin/2392703?ref=bmoe`)

Comment: New version of PhotoSwipe was released recently, it's quite good, check it out - http://photoswipe.com/